# Как пишется: "и когда это правда кому-нибудь помогала?"

Tags: пунктуация

Подруга утверждает, что предложение написано неправильно, что там пропущена запятая. Я же уверена, что все правильно, никакие запятые там не нужны. Кто из нас прав?

Comment: А в каком месте запятая якобы пропущена? Интересно же понять логику, а не получить бесплатную консультацию.

Answer (score 2):

И **когда это** правда кому-нибудь помогала?

**Действительно, запятые здесь не нужны.** Но если всё-таки вам кажется, что запятая нужна, попробуйте определить синтаксическую роль сомнительных слов - такими словами вам могут показаться  **"это" и "правда".**

1) **ЭТО** в данном случае усилительная частица.  Согласно словарю, она усиливает отдельные слова в предложении: **Кто это** пришёл? **Куда это** ты идёшь? Ведь **это я** тебе звонил.

2) Слово "**правда**" здесь **подлежащее** (главный член предложения), но в других  случаях может быть **вводным словом,** например: Были, **правда**, неприятности, но обошлось.

Comment: *Если кто-то сомневается в этом*  - ну вот, к примеру, я сомневаюсь. *то ему следует определить синтаксическую роль слов* - определил. Не помогает.  ))) И вообще,, можно вас попросить поменьще менторства. Вы так вслед за Галиной Аванесовой всех новичков распугаете.

Answer (score 1):

Вы совершенно правы, запятых тут не нужно! Просто нет причин для них. Обосновать можно постановку каких-то знаков препинания, а отсутствие обосновывать не надо. Так что спросите у своей подруги, *почему* она считает, что запятая нужна.

Comment: *Обосновать можно постановку каких-то знаков препинания, а отсутствие обосновывать не надо* - не "можно", а "нужно". А так - в десятку.

Comment: Артем, а вот такой простой пример: Мы поднялись ни свет ни заря.  Здесь надо объяснять отсутствие знаков препинания?

Comment: Да, Вы правы! Действительно, тут можно объяснить отсутствие запятой тем, что это устойчивое выражение.

Comment: *Да, Вы правы! Действительно, тут можно объяснить отсутствие запятой тем, что это устойчивое выражение* - здесь надо объяснять только потому, что это изъятие из основного правила. Без объяснения этого основного правила (или хотя бы ссылки на него)  по которому запятую ставить надо, всё равно никуда не деться. Так что основной принцип ***"мотивируется знак, а не его отсутствие"*** не подлежит переосмыслению.

Answer (score 0):

В этом контексте слово "правда" нерядовое. Будет уместно писать его с заглавной буквы (Правда) или курсивом. Сомневаюсь, что можно сделать акцент на этом слове (при записи фразы) посредством каких либо знаков препинания.